# Apache Ivy Resolution Concerns

Tags: apache, configuration, ivy

New to Apache Ivy and I'm configuring the `latest-strategies` element in my settings file, and am opting to go with the lexiconographic strategy for a number of reasons. But something just dawned on me, and has me worried about Ivy in general. I'm sure I'm just not seeing the "forest" through the "trees", but I absolutely need to gain clarity on this before I can proceed.

My project will use several other homegrown JARs as dependencies. Other developers may be actively working on these other JARs, and may introduce a bug at some point. If my project uses Ivy to always pull down the latest version of these other dependencies, then Ivy may inadvertently pull down a new bug when it goes to build.

What's the common solution here, or what do best practices dictate?

Is there a way to cherry pick which versions of which JARs my project uses? That way I'm not concerned with `latest-strategies` at all, or lexiconographic order, etc. That would seem to alleviate the problem, but may violate best practices.

Any input is appreciated, as always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such situation we used to use tags on trunk. When developer creates tag he must change a version number of a published ivy module. In this case when you want to use stable version of module you could resolve it by certain version (1.2.3) or by latest version from some range (1.2.+). The latest-development strategy pull out the latest unstable trunk or branch version of a module.